# Android BLE disable pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I develop an app where an Android device acts as a peripheral and advertises with some specific data which is then recognized by the central device and the connection is established.

The problem is: when I'm out of the range of the previously paired central device (so I'm not connected and started advertising again) and meet another central device (which I was not connected before), I'm getting a pairing request (which is reasonable as I'm advertising with the same data). How can I prevent starting a new pairing request if I have already paired with some other central device before? Is it possible without changing advertisement data?

Comment: When a connection is established, any side can request pairing. So why does your code on the central side (or peripheral side) initiate pairing?

Comment: I'm talking about the case when the peripheral **isn't** connected to any central device at the moment but it **was** in the past so the phone knows this pairing. As I'm not connected, I have to advertise to be able to be detected by the central that I was connected to. But at the same time I want to decline pairing with other central devices. I have limited access to central code so trying to resolve this on the app side.

Comment: There's no API in Android to reject a pairing attempt as far as I know for Bluetooth.

Comment: I see, thanks anyway.